# partial .txt file to datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i have a user interface form that let's you upload a text file to a datagridview as follows

```
Sub Datagrid()
    Dim sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
    Using stream As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(TextBox1.Text)
        Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
            While (line IsNot Nothing)
                Dim columns = line.Split(";")
                line = reader.ReadLine()
                Dim index = Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows(index).SetValues(columns)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
    sw.Stop()
End Sub
```

Well, now my problem is that i don't want to put the full txt file in that datagridview, just from line N.
Is it possible to do that? **Like creating a querytabel and selecting a fixed value?**

p.e., in line 5 there's always the text "Values:" . Can i select all the lines after that to put in the datagridview? i googled everywhere but found nothing. and there's no "sample" code to give me a start . thank you all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim n As Integer = 5
    Dim lines As IEnumerable(Of String) = IO.File.ReadAllLines("textbox1.text").Skip(n) 
'Gets every line after a certain line count

    'Create a new datatable and add some columns
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.AddRange((From columnIndex As Integer In Enumerable.Range(1, lines.First.Split(";"c).Count) Select New DataColumn("Column" & columnIndex.ToString())).ToArray())

    'Add each line as a row to the datatable
    For Each line As String In lines
        dt.Rows.Add(line.Split(";"c))
    Next

    'Set the datasource of the datagridview
    MyDataGridView.DataSource = dt
```